# Bootstrap Mobile Site Moving Side to Side

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, ruby-on-rails-4, responsive-design

I've used Bootstrap to create a responsive site.  The problem is that if a person scrolls to either side the site moves with it.

I have this in my application.html.erb:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

Here is a visual of what it looks like:

[image]

If anyone can point me in the right direction I'd appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you post your html, css and js in a jsfiddle please

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try to set the body in the CSS to:

```
 /*CSS*/
 body{
     width:100%;
     height:100%;
     overflow-x: hidden;
 }
```

Had the same issue on my site and that fixed it. If that does not work add

```
 <head>
     ...
     <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
     ...
 </head>
```

Comment: Any time let me know if you need anything else